# display the content of a combobox recover from Zend_form

Tags: php, zend-framework, combobox, zend-form

I have a form with a combobox

```
  /*Business user type*/
            $Busertype = new Zend_Form_Element_Select("Busertype");
        $Busertype ->setLabel('Business user type')
          ->addFilter('StripTags') //StripTags : Enlève les caractères HTML
              ->setRequired(true)
               -> setMultiOptions(array(
                                '0' => '-Select your business type-',
                    '1' => 'Owner',
                                    '2' => 'Suplier',
                                    '3' => 'Representative',
                                    '4' => 'Shop'
        ));
```

I want to retrieve the contents of the combobox, but when i do `echo($busername)` i retrieve the value of the combobox. So how can i display the content of the combobox

Part of the action

```
  $form = new Application_Form_Inscriptionbu(); 
     $this->view->form = $form; //nous assignons le formulaire à la vue pour affichagee
     if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  //Le formulaire est-il posté ?
     $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); // récupère les infos des formulaires

     if ($form->isValid($formData)) { //Si le formulaire passe la validation
        $v = $form->getValues();
        $busername =$v['Busername'];
        echo($busername);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to redisplay the text from the option selected, you can use `getMultiOption`.

```
if ($form->isValid($formData)) { //Si le formulaire passe la validation
    $v         = $form->getValues();
    $busername = $v['Busername'];

    echo "You selected $busername which is called " . 
         $form->getElement('Busername')->getMultiOption($busername) . 
         '<br />';
}
```

Comment: i try your solution but nothing is displayed

Comment: Sorry, since it is a multi-select, you get back an array of values.  I updated the answer showing how to get the first option that was selected.  To see them all, you can loop over `$busername` to get each option that was selected and then call getMultiOption for each one.

Comment: [Zend_Form_Element_MultiSelect::getMultiOption()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Form_Element_Multiselect.html#\Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect::getMultiOption%28%29)  It comes from `Zend_Form_Element_Multi` which is extended by `Zend_Form_Element_MultiSelect`.

Comment: thank you so match for your detailed response but i use a combobox witch i create with `Zend_Form_Element_Select` so i can't use the methode `getMultiOption`

Comment: can you please help me solve the problem when i use `Zend_Form_Element_Select `

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused.  I see now you are using a regular select, not a multi-select.  Select also extends from Zend_Form_Element_Multi so you can do the same.  Let me update my answer though.

Comment: I try but i didn't find the methode `getMultiOption`

Comment: Take a look now and see if that works for you.  I confirmed it is also working with a regular Zend_Form_Element_Select